# How to show my own contract name in Token Tracker field of an ERC1155 Contract?

Tags: contract-development, remix, polygon

I am developing an NFT Drop site contract. I want my NFT Contract to be named from ERC1155 to provide a name in the constructor. I have watched and followed many tutorials. They all work the same and so I am following them. But my Token Tracker name is ERC1155.
Can Anyone please suggest to me how to solve this issue???

Here is my contract Link: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x69A66176A9d8E5EB207CA8Ed66bdBF318f965523#code

What I am getting

[image]

What I should be getting

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add name function on your 1155 contract.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";

contract ItemSFT is ERC1155("") {
constructor() {
    _mint(msg.sender, 1, 1, "");

}

function name() public view returns(string memory){
    return "TEST";
   }
}
```

[Contract Example](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/0x4999b113a50ca991a10e73430e3425ed9060b460)

Comment: i fixed the code here as it can't verify at the moment

Comment: Please do so that I may see the code.

Comment: How it will set the name of contract???
Still, let me try if it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the name of your contract:

```
string public name;
string public symbol;
constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol )ERC1155(""){    
    name = _name;
    symbol = _symbol
}
```

In your contract, you have the wrong names for your public variables, the name of the public string variable representing the name of your contract has to be "name", not "_name", the same goes for the symbol, the variable has to be named "symbol" not "_symbol" so that the tracker can look for the correct data in your contract.

Comment: I am doing the same code you can see it in the contract I provided above.
But it is not showing the contract name.